# "Out of memory" stops the row counter

Tags: vba, excel, out-of-memory, counter

- Column "A": list of the tex file names
- Column "B": how many rows should be in the text files
- Column "C": how many rows are there in the text files factually
- E1: source path
- E2: limiter, the text file rows will be counted, if the RowInSummary number of the text file is equal or lower than E2

My script counts the rows of every files. But if I set the limiter too high (like 500.000 or 1M) or just there are too many files, the script does not count the rows of every files because the program run out of memory. (The limiter is not necessary, I have put it the "run out of memory" issue, originally I don't want to use it.)

[image]

```
Sub counter()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim longtext As String
    Dim lines As Variant
    Dim GoToNum As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    GoToNum = 2
    Start = 3

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(Start, 1))
        GoToNum = GoToNum + 1
        Start = Start + 1
    Loop

    For i = 3 To GoToNum

        If Cells(i, 2).Value <= Cells(2, 5).Value Then

            ConOrg = Cells(1, 4).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value

            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(ConOrg, ForReading, False)
            longtext = ts.ReadAll

            ts.Close
            lines = Split(longtext, vbLf)
            Cells(i, 3) = UBound(lines) - LBound(lines) - 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

How can the script count rows of every files with out "run out of memory"?

Comment: Declare them as `Long` instead of `Integer'.

Comment: I have tried it, but not the GoToNum and Start cause this problem.

Comment: a) Test if this is caused by a specific file only b) test if `Set ts = Nothing` helps after `.Close`

Comment: a) If I run the script with one (or many small size) file there is no any problem, b) if 'Set ts = Nothing' it gives an error message "Object variable or With lock variable not set".

Comment: Also, `Dim fso As New FileSystemObject` shouldn't be inside the loop. It should be declared before the loop starts.

Comment: In fact all the variables should be declared before the loop starts.

Comment: My bad, It's corrected.

Comment: @sktneer In fact as long as the variable is declared before its first use, you can declare it in a loop without problem. But the variable scope won't be limited to the loop, and the variable will be declared even if the loop is not executed. So it is still a good idea to put them outside.

Comment: @VincentG Yeah, I agree but as you said there is one thing known as good practice that's why I pointed that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of how you can avoid fso and still do what you want.

```
   Sub LinesCounter()

    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SomeText As String
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim LineCounter As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim GoToNum, Start As Long

    Path = Cells(1, 5).Value
    Start = 3

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(Start, 1))
        GoToNum = GoToNum + 1
        Start = Start + 1
    Loop

    For i = 3 To GoToNum
            FileName = Cells(i, 1).Value

            Open Path & FileName For Input As #1
                Do Until EOF(1)
                    Line Input #1, TextLine
                    'SomeText = SomeText & " " & TextLine
                    LineCounter = LineCounter + 1
                Loop
            Close #1
            'you can comment line below, it's only for testing
            Debug.Print "There is a: " & LineCounter & " lines in " & _
            FileName & " text file."

            'Adding values to Excel sheet
            Cells(i, 3) = LineCounter
    Next i
    End Sub
```